# django-rest framework filtering error?

Tags: django

Iam trying to implement the web api for shifts , here ShiftsViewSet is my

api view , while running this project im trying to filter according to id , but its showing error ,

ShiftsViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method ,

can any one help me to do solve this problem,

thanks in adavance.

Comment: im not understood whats is error ?

Comment: do you want to set  a filtered queryset?

Comment: def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
 queryset = ShiftFilters(request.GET,qeryset=Shift.objects.all().order_by('-id'))
paginator = Paginator(queryset, 20)
page = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('page')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('id')
    queryset = Shift.objects.filter(pk=id)
    ...
```